# Dynamic graph (?) - combination of connections between vertices that for each 3 exist min 1 edge

Tags: algorithms, graphs, dynamic-programming

I have to find number of ways (combination) to create graph that for each 3 vertices there are minimum 2 vertices connected. There is n vertices. For example when n=3, there are 7 possible combinations. How can I make this with maybe dynamic programming?

Comment: Try finding what graphs satisfying this condition look like.

Comment: Your graphs are the complements of triangle-free graphs.

Answer (score 2):

Your condition on the graph is the same as requiring its complement to be triangle-free. It is known that there are a lot of triangle-free graph. Indeed, since every bipartite graph is triangle-free, if we fix a partition of the vertex set into two sets of size $n/2$ (assuming for simplicity that $n$ is even), then we already get $2^{n^2/4}$ triangle-free graphs. It turns out that there aren't that much more, see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/159494/determine-or-estimate-the-number-of-maximal-triangle-free-graphs-on-n-vertices) on mathoverflow.

Perhaps you'd be interested in a paper on [generating maximal triangle-free graphs up to isomorphism](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/PL00021176) (in your case, you will be generating *minimal* graphs satisfying your condition), whose number is more manageable.

Comment: Okay, so I need to generate triangle-free graphs and for all of these count combination of complements these graphs?  How I can make that for expamle when n=3? (Answer is 7)

Comment: Use a software package such as [nauty](http://pallini.di.uniroma1.it/).

Comment: I cannot use that because of my software, is there any way to generate all possible triangle-free graphs with n vertices? (the best in C++)

Comment: I just pointed out a way: use nauty. You can use it both as a standalone program and as a library.

Comment: Yes, of course but I need to write an algorithm in C++ without any additionally libraries or something like that

Comment: That's an artificial restriction. In real life it is usually encouraged to use external libraries. You can always generate all graphs and filter out those which do not satisfy your constraint.